# Clion 1.1.1 use CMakeList.txt to add library headers for unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, cmake, clion

I never used CMake before so please excuse me.

My project has a "unity" folder that contains version 2.3.0 of the unit test library). unity_fixture.h contains "#define TEST(..." which is used like the following:

`#include "unity_fixture.h"
    ...
    TEST(xformatc, Simple) {
      char output[20];
      TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(13, testFormat(output, "Hello world\r\n"));
      TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING("Hello world\r\n", output);
    }`

I added "include_directories(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/unity)" to my CMakeLists.txt file. Still CLion does not find the declaration of TEST and I get tons of errors.
I did try to add all the unity files with set(SOURCE_FILES unity/unity_fixture.h..." but this did not work either.

edit 08.09.2015
I found out something strange. If I call cmake from command line it creates a file "DependInfo.cmake" with the following contents:

`# The set of languages for which implicit dependencies are needed:
    set(CMAKE_DEPENDS_LANGUAGES
      )
    # The set of files for implicit dependencies of each language:`

```
# Targets to which this target links.
set(CMAKE_TARGET_LINKED_INFO_FILES
  )

# The include file search paths:
set(CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH
  "unity"
  "cmsis/inc"
  "freertos/inc"
  )
set(CMAKE_CXX_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_Fortran_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH})
set(CMAKE_ASM_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH})
```

The CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH stuff is missing in the file that is created by CLion. I believe that is the reason why it does not find the headers. Question is how do I tell CLion to create the CMAKE_C_TARGET_INCLUDE_PATH stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your project structure is :

```
project root
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Some source files
└── unity
    └── unity_fixture.h
```

If you use CMake to include files :

```
set(INCLUDE_DIR ./unity)
include_directories(${INCLUDE_DIR})
```

Your include must be : `#include <unity_fixture.h>`

Or you can use without using CMake  to include directories : `#include "unity/unity_fixture.h"`

Comment: hmm, I do not see how your proposed solution is different to mine but I tried it anyway... unfortunately it did not fix the problem :(. I should have said in the beginning that the project structure itself is fine. It compiles perfectly using GNU make.

Comment: hmm, ok CMake creates makefiles (or something equivalent depending on the OS/what you says him to do) using `<>` instead of `"""` is the main modification, the other stuff is just to make your CMake easier to read. After CLion creates the files but in his personal space, under `~/.clion11/system/cmake/generated`. At this time i can't figure what is wrong, can you paste your full CMake/Project here or with github (or something like that) ?

Comment: project is here: https://github.com/finklabs/epiclibs but I did not check in the CMakeLists.txt file since it is broken.

Comment: I've tried to do that : http://i.imgur.com/QSbQgYT.png. I'm not familiar with unity so there is little error with it. But CLion finds unity this way(you can use `""` to include).

Comment: this works. One has to include the directories and include the headers in SOURCE_FILES, too.